# the adverb "all" as a direct object

Tags: adverbs, direct-objects

> [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all#examples):
>
> **1.** *I forgot **all** about paying the bill*.
>
> [collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/all_1):
>
> **2.** *He loves animals and he knows **all** about them*.

As written in the dictionaries, "*all*" is an adverb here. I absolutely can't understand it. Why is it not a pronoun here?

If it's an adverb, then how is it possible that an adverb is used as a direct object? Because as far as I can judge, "*all*" is a direct object here.

Thanks!

Comment: It's arguable that 'forget about' is a multi-word verb. Compare 'I remembered / remembered about the earlier incident' ///  'I forgot / forgot about the earlier incident'. 'All' is then arguably an intensifier, 'I completely forgot about ...'. ////// Of course, one can argue that 'I forgot everything about paying [/having to pay] the bill' is a better comparator, especially considering where 'all' occurs, and this is especially true for your second example. Perhaps it's best to see these as idioms, 'forget all about' and 'know all about'. 'He knows all about John / algae' ...

Comment: and 'He knows everything about John / algae' are not exact synonyms (though the two forms are sometimes interchangeable).